# jquery plugin, set property value to ajax data

Tags: jquery, html, pagination, jquery-pagination

I am struggling here.  Using this simple pagination plug (http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/#page-19) and trying to set the number of items to a value returned from an ajax call.  But it will never work.  If I set the number of items to a hard coded number it works just fine, but every for every letter I call this function with the number of items will change so I want to do it with this call.

This is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        var numNames;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/Name/GetBoyCount?letter=" + viewModel.Letter(),
            complete: function (data) {
                $(selector).pagination('updateItems', parseInt(data));

            }
        });

        $(function () {
            $(selector).pagination({
                items: 100,
                itemsOnPage: 175,
                cssStyle: 'light-theme'
            });
        });

// etc
```

Comment: an integer that is returned, in this case 3320

Comment: Oh apparently I can use +data to convert to int.  Which works here.  Damn sorry I should have waited 5 minutes before writing this.

Comment: if `+data` works, remember to always use a radix, as that's the real issue -> `parseInt(data, 10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax call is probably finishing before your initialization, try taking the initialization code out of the `.ready()` call back.

Change this

```
$(function(){
    $(selector).pagination({
        etc....
    });
});
```

To this
    $(selector).pagination({
        etc....
    });

Also `$(document).ready(function(){})` is the same as `$(function(){})` so you are calling `.ready()` from inside another ready check.